# What is the best way to make my electric motorbike efficient?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, efficiency, current

I am currently doing research on making an electric dirtbike, but I am struggling with how I can make it at as efficient as possible.

I think I will use a BLDC motor of 2000 W and 60V and have a RPM of 4600 loaded, with a rated current of 33A.

I thought the best way to make the bike efficient was to use the motor on maximum half the RPM, so 2300 maximum. Then I will use a 1 to 3 on the link from the wheel to the motor to make it easier for the motor. With a perimeter of 190cm of the wheel times the RPM of 766 (2300:3,) it will go 87.4 km/hour.

- How much current do you think the motor will use if the maximum is 33A but I’m using half the RPM of the motor?
- Is the way I just explained the best way to make my electric motor bike?

Comment: The best way to make any vehicle efficient is to drive it at low speed (and at a constant speed). The thought process is this: You begin at standstill and end at standstill therefore all the energy taken to get up to speed is lost when the journey is ended so, if your maximum speed is low, it will waste less energy than if your maximum speed is high.

Comment: that’s not a answer to my question, can anyone help me with my question?

Comment: @Pacalvs sorry, trying to be a bit overly nitpicky here on purpose: it's actually an answer to your question! If you wanted your bike to be efficient in a specific usage scenario, please try to describe the actual usage scenario. A motor isn't efficient over all loads/speeds, that's true, but as Andy says, the least energy overall can only be used at the least speed possible. The "half max RPM" thing seems .. wrong and not coming from an argument? Where do you get that from? Why would RPM be more important than work/torque?

Comment: Yeah exactly, it’s not coming from an argument because that exactly the thing I don’t understand. I don’t know if lowering the rpm will be more efficient then do something with the torque.  So my 2 questions are: how much amps do you think the motor will use if the max is 33A but I’m using half the rpm of the motor? And is the way I just explained the best way to make my electric motor bike.  Can you please help my answering these questions!

Comment: Have you looked at pictures of 2 kW electric bikes on-line and do you think that what is basically a motorized standard pushbike will cut-the-mustard as a dirt bike? I have no idea because I don't know what you mean as a dirt bike. I've seen a 6 kW trial bike with a max speed of 47 mph

Comment: Here is a link so you can see what I mean with a dirtbike. https://images.app.goo.gl/HShXkYqZBRZm4vS6A. I also want a kW of 3,4,5 but I also want a high radius of kilometers. That’s what I want to know. But no one has directly given answer to my question. I want to make a motorbike like the link. My goal is to go like 75km/hour. But also have a radius of 100/150 kilometers. But if I take the 33 amps of loaded current and a battery of 60v 30Ah it wil last max a hour and that’s to low. So that is why I asked what the most efficient way is to make my dirtbike.

Comment: The current taken will vary enormously according to the load being placed on it so nobody's going to be able to directly answer. You need to calculate the power you're expecting your motor to deliver and work backwards.

Comment: Your link doesn't appear to work and your original question stated 2 kW but now you are appearing to be stating something higher than this with some ambiguity in the value. Engineering is all about tying things down to a specification. Have you looked at the power and efficiency curves of the motors you may be considering?

Answer (score 2):

2 kW is not a lot for a motorbike. I can put out 1 kW as a cyclist, for a few seconds at least (after that it drops to a few hundred). If you want motorbike performance, you are well into two figures of kW, so 10+.

The maximum current that a motor can handle has several limits, one is thermal, the other is demagnetising the motor. Almost always, the thermal one bites first. The maximum current is not that sensitive to speed. At higher speed, you have increased losses due to churning the air in the motor, but you also have increased cooling, due to the same churn. It's a matter of detail of the particular motor which one wins out.

The current limit is important, as that limits the torque, and therefore the power at any speed. If you limit yourself to half the rated speed, then you'll limit yourself to half the rated power. Your arbitrary half maximum rpm decision has just bought you a 1 kW motor.

BLDC motors are quite efficient. Once it's geared correctly, there's not a lot you can do other than alter your riding style to use less energy to cover a given distance. Assuming a reasonable controller, your motor will consume what's needed to make your bike push through the air and climb hills against gravity.

Are you assuming single speed, or will you use a gearbox? Perhaps the single most effective thing you can do to increase efficiency is to use a gearbox, to keep the motor running in its most efficient nearly-maximum-speed regime.

You can over-speed (a bit, with care, limited by efficiency and armature strength) and over-torque (a bit, for short periods of time, limited by overheating) a motor. While the motor will be running at lower efficiency during either scenario, it can allow you to choose a single speed that's a bit more efficient overall, if your required performance contains only short bursts of high speed or high torque.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought the best way to make the bike efficient was to use the motor on maximum half the RPM

PWming down the effective voltage to achieve a loaded RPM half that loaded RPM at full throttle says nothing about efficiency. You are mixing and matching things all over the place.

- The rule-of-thumb for DC motors is **max efficiency** is a loaded RPM
  that is **6/7ths** of no-load RPM or a loaded torque that is
  **1/7th** of stall torque. *At the effective operating voltage of the motor for all parameters*.
- The rule-of-thumb for DC motors is **max power** is a loaded RPM that
  is **half** of no-load RPM or a loaded torque that is **half** of
  stall torque. *At the effective operating voltage of the motor for
  all parameters*.

[image]
https://islproducts.com/design-note/how-to-read-dc-motor-gear-motor-performance-curves/

That graph is for ONE operating voltage: the effective operating voltage of the motor.

Since no-load RPM and stall torque are dependent on voltage you can't cheat by doing something like PWMing 60V at 50% duty cycle to synthesize 30V and then use peak efficiency conditions for 60V. The max efficiency conditions must match the effective motor voltage.

Therefore, if you synthesize an effective operating voltage of 30V by using 50% duty cycle when running off 60V, and wish to achieve max efficiency while doing that you cannot use 60V no-load RPM or stall torque to determine max efficiency (or max power); You must use 30V. For max efficiency you need to size your wheels and gearing so your loaded RPM is 6/7ths no-load RPM at 30V (not 60V).

You could also adjust your throttle until your RPM matches the max efficiency RPM for your effective voltage. Don't go too low in your throttle though (see last paragraph).

This could mean a much slower speed with the same motor a or much larger motor is required to travel at the same speed if your E-bike and its motor was originally sized for max power.

Full throttle on an electronic controller is also more efficient than partial throttle (and motor drivers don't work well at lower duty cycles below 50-70%) but sizing everything to be maximally efficient at full throttle comes at the price of having no more throttle to power through things to maintain speed at the expense of efficiency. But if your goal truly is "as efficient as possible" then that is the price you pay unless you use variable gearing (a transmission). Efficiency = sluggish.

I'm guessing you are going to sacrifice some efficiency for performance. You can also see from the efficiency curve that you are better off overloading it around max efficiency than underloading it.

Comment: Is that graph applicable to BLDC motors per OP's question or more common regular DC brushed motors only?

Comment: @JohnU It's applicable to both (DC commutated permanent magnet motors).

Comment: Thank you @DKNguyen. So if you can choose the BLDC motor of 1kw, 2kw and 3kw 60 or 72v(that are the most motors on sites like Alibaba) which one would you chose en how would you set it up? and how would you setup the gear on the motor and on the wheel? You really helping me thanks

Comment: @Pacalvs It really comes down to your specifications. You are going to need to decide your desired acceleration, how big a battery you want to deal with, your speed at maximum efficiency and the inclination of maximum efficiency (presumably horizontal). And then you need to decide what throttle you want that maximum efficiency to be at which decides how much headroom you have to power through things like hills. Then you need to see what your gearing can achieve.

Comment: Then you go through these calculations repeatedly tinkering with gearing, motor, acceleration, and max efficiency speed until you get a balance that you can live with: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31501/how-can-i-calculate-the-power-and-torque-required-for-the-motor-on-a-wheeled-rob/31502#31502

Comment: For the first iteration I recommend you just outright do not specify an acceleration and go for maximum efficiency. Then back-calculate to see what kind of acceleration that gives you. It's probably going to be lower than what you want and that's where you start making concessions. Another possible first iteration is just to pick your ideal parameters for performance (speed and acceleration) and see the unreasonable ridiculously oversized motor and parts that this probably requires.

Comment: All this requires that you any motor you look at has the no-load RPM, and stall torque is provided. You can't pick a motor based on calculations without that data. And the data will probably only be provided at the one operating voltage. You'll need to start estimating the data at voltages below that. Or you can treated the rated motor data as where you want to run at max efficiency which would be full throttle. Or you can treat the rated motor data as max power (full throttle) for the worst conditions (hills) you expect and then ease off to get the max efficiency operation.

Comment: It's iterative and not a direct calculation from A to B. It will require fiddling with parameters and your requirements until you get something that you can live with that is also achievable with the parts available.

Comment: Semi-related, a peak efficiency of 43% is less than impressive. How do BEV motors compare?

Comment: @hacktastical Are you referring to a graph in the source link? Curves for small brushless motors (<600W) I've seen have curves that peak at around 88% for the motor alone.

Comment: The 43% figure came from the text you referenced for that particular gearmotor.  A bit of research came up with about 75% for induction motors. But there are claims of 80-90% for BEV motors, which I can’t seem to verify with any hard information. There’s this Nissan fluff piece that claims some high numbers for example: https://www.renaultgroup.com/en/news-on-air/news/the-energy-efficiency-of-an-electric-car-motor/

Comment: @hacktastical Well if you subscribe to larger motors being more efficient, it wouldn't be surprising to see a huge permanent magnet BEV motor to be an upwards of 90% when a tiny DC brushless motor can be 88%. That's just for the motor on its own though. No transmission. At a single operating point.

Comment: That makes sense: bigger motor = lower winding resistance = less loss. I’d still be interested to see what a dyno says through.

Answer (score 0):

A motor's efficiency is largely determined by resistive losses, so a larger motor will have less winding resistance, and will have lower losses at a given current draw. It may have lower efficiency based on the power capability, but it will likely be more efficient based on power out / power in.

I made an on-line EV calculator that can provide approximate values for things like power needed for a particular acceleration (or hill-climbing) at a given speed, and watt-hours per mile. These will take into account important variables such as weight of vehicle and driver, and aerodynamic drag.

http://enginuitysystems.com/EVCalculator.htm

A well designed electric car will have something like 200 Wh/mile at nominal 50 MPH on a flat road. I would expect a dirt bike to use something like 50 Wh/mile. So for a range of 60 miles, you would need about 3000 Wh, which would mean a 60V battery with 50 Ah capacity, and considering overall efficiency and avoiding draining the battery below 20% SOC, you probably need at least 100 Ah.